# Why does function not start after user input being returned from another function

Tags: c, function, return

That's the code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char street;
    int number;
    char postalcode;
} Person;

void print(Person p) {
    printf("Street: %s\n", p.street);
    printf("Number: %d\n", p.number);
    printf("Postal code: %s\n", p.postalcode);
}

Person signUp() {
  Person person;

  printf("In which street do you live on?: \n");
  scanf("%s", &person.street);

  printf("What is your number?: \n");
  scanf("%d", &person.number);

  printf("what is your postal code?: \n");
  scanf("%s", &person.postalcode);

  return person;
 }

int main(void) {
  Person person;

  person = signUp();
    print(person); 

  return 0;
}
```

I tried to make the "signUp" function return the user inputs to another function called "print", so it would print the values from the previous function. The "signUp" function works just fine, but the "print" function never starts.

Comment: `street` is a single character, `%s` is for a character string. You need to change it to something like `char street[30]` and `char postalcode[10]`

Comment: Go back to your textbook or tutorial and reread the chapter on characters and strings.

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comments by someone else, when using the `%s` conversion format specifier with `scanf`, you must make sure that the memory buffer whose address you pass to `scanf` is sufficiently large. If you only pass the address of a single character, then you only have room for storing a single null character (i.e. an empty string).

Comment: Question: Why is the code so "developed" as to deal with 3 fields, yet buggy... Advice: "Incremental development"... Write only a very few lines of code before pausing to test that what has been written functions as it is meant to. (PS: `scanf()` has a return code that is not being checked by this code.)

Comment: I really need to develop this sense of testing every bit of code. I just wrote everything at once and tested the final product.

Comment: For your own sake (and fewer questions posted to SO), do develop that habit... You will attain the goal (working code) much faster when confident that each elaboration is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You reading and writing strings with `%s` but your variables are a single char (which would be the format string `%c`).
2. When reading a string with `scanf()` always use a maximum field width.  I am using a `str()` macro here to not repeat myself.  Note: usually we prefer using `sizeof()` but you need `sizeof(p->street)-1` and the order of evaluation of macros gets in the way.
3. There is nothing wrong with passing in a struct by value and returning them by value, however, this implies copies so we usually pass these in via a pointer instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define POSTALCODE_LEN 5
#define STREET_LEN 20
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

typedef struct {
    char street[STREET_LEN+1];
    int number;
    char postalcode[POSTALCODE_LEN+1];
} Person;

void print(const Person *p) {
    printf("Street: %s\n", p->street);
    printf("Number: %d\n", p->number);
    printf("Postal code: %s\n", p->postalcode);
}

void signUp(Person *person) {
    printf("In which street do you live on?: \n");
    scanf("%" str(STREET_LEN) "s", person->street);

    printf("What is your number?: \n");
    scanf("%d", &person->number);

    printf("what is your postal code?: \n");
    scanf("%" str(POSTALCODE_LEN) "s", person->postalcode);
}

int main(void) {
    Person person;
    signUp(&person);
    print(&person);
}
```

I realize that the `typedef` saves you from writing `struct Person` but the downside is that it imports "Person" into the same name space as variable so you cannot do `Person Person` but have to use a lowercase `person`.  If you need to talk to someone about your code it becomes more tedious "lowercase person" or "uppercase person" to differentiate.  Personally (pun), I would use use a short variable name to get around it, i.e. `Person p`.

I also find snake case easier to read than camel case (`sign_up()` vs `signUp()`), and I find the namespace rules easier to remember (constants are upper case, rest is lowercase; with camel case it's methods starts with lower case and then you upper case each words except ... etc).

Comment: Thank you so much for the info, I started using the camel case when learning JS and now I just use it automatically. Also, can you explain the usage of "&" before the argument at "print(&person)"?

Comment: `void print(const Person *p)` now takes a pointer while `person` is an object so we need to take the address of it with `&`.